# Does $f(x(s)) = 0$ imply that $x(t) = x(s)$ for $t\geq s$ in an autonomous ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an autonomous ODE $x' = f(x)$ and $x(0) = x_0$, do we necessarily have that if $f(x(s)) = 0$ then $x(t) = x(s)$ for $t\geq s$? I understand that this similar to finding equilibrium solutions, and I understand intuitively that since $f(x(s)) = x'(s)= 0$ then there will be no change in $x(t)$ for all times after $t$. But I am having trouble formally showing this.

For example, what prevents scenarios where $x(t) = (t-1)^3$, in which $x'(1) = 0$ but $x(t)\neq x(1)$ for $t\geq 1$? Although I know that in this example, $x(t)$ is not autonomous, I was wondering how we can show that autonomous ODEs don't run into problems where $x(t)$ have local maxima or minima or inflection points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only applies if $f$ is differentiable in that root, or at least Lipschitz in some interval around it.

See the usual counter example $x'=2\sqrt{|x|}$ where $x(t)=0$ for $t<c$ and $x(t)=(t-c)^2$ for $t\ge c$ are all solutions for any $c>0$.